# How to convert object type between two webservice instances in Powershell?

Tags: web-services, powershell, reporting-services, types, converters

I'm programming with Powershell for SSRS webserivce.

I have two SSRS site, I want to use GetSubscriptionProperties method to get subscription info, then copy it to another site using CreateSubscription.

```
$SSRS0 = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $Uri0 -UseDefaultCredential;
$SSRS1 = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $Uri1 -UseDefaultCredential;
.....
$SSRS0.GetSubscriptionProperties($subscription.SubscriptionID, [ref]$extSettings, [ref]$desc, [ref]$active, [ref]$status, [ref]$eventType, [ref]$matchData, [ref]$values);
$SSRS1.CreateSubscription($URL, $extSettings, $desc, $eventType, $matchData, $values);
```

Then I got the error:

```
Cannot convert argument "ExtensionSettings", with value: "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1er_ReportService20
10_asmx_WSDL.ExtensionSettings", for "CreateSubscription" to type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy5er_Report
Service2010_asmx_WSDL.ExtensionSettings": "Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1er_ReportServ
ice2010_asmx_WSDL.ExtensionSettings" value of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1er_ReportService2010_asm
x_WSDL.ExtensionSettings" to type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy5er_ReportService2010_asmx_WSDL.ExtensionS
ettings"."
```

It's trying to convert the type from site A webservice type to site B webservice type, in fact, it's the same type, but create by two New-WebServiceProxy statements.

How can I convert it without copying all members manually?

I've tried these ways from Internet, but no help:

1. Use -as operator to convert, $null returns.
2. Use -namespace in both two New-WebServiceProxy, only one proxy works, another corrupted.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the code that generates the error?

Comment: Another question. Does `$ext.Extension` return anything?

Comment: Update the code, $ext.Extension is not empty

Comment: did you try using `$ext.Extension` instead of `$ext`?

Comment: $ext.Extension is a string, create a object of type from ssrs2 then copy that value is OK, but for $ext.ParameterValues, it's complicated. I'm looking for a general way to solve this problem instead of doing deep copy manually

Comment: @bychance I'm having this exact issue right now.  Did you find a solution?